# Reverting svn code to particular previous version

Tags: svn

Is it possible to revert `svn` code to any particular previous versions. For example consider my code is in the `svn` revision of 200. Is it possible to revert this to revision of 100. I know check out option. But i want to know this one. Help me..

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do? For example, do you want to temporarily go back to 100 e.g to debug a bug in that version? Were rev 101-200 a dead end, and you would like to start over based on 100, or do you want to permanently erase revs 101-200 from your history? (There are many other possibilities.) within knowing what you want to achieve, it's difficult to provide specific help.

Comment: @oefe Actually i want to change something in 100 revision and commit it.. And also i want to keep all 101-200 revision.. How to achieve..

Comment: Why can't you just make your change on rev 200 instead?

Comment: @oefe i need to test something with that code of 100...If i will not get proper solution, i have to test with some changes without 101-200 revision code.

Comment: If only for testing, why do you want to commit it?

Comment: @oefe i need to test something with that code of 100...   **If i will not get proper solution, i have to test with some changes and commit  without 101-200 revision code.**  –  ANBU.SANKAR 7 mins ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -r in the update command.

```
svn up -r 100
```

Then you can commit or not as you want.

Comment: @Peter Ivanov If i change something in 100 revision and try to commit this change, what will happen..? Will create any trouble because already the code is in 200 revision..? Or will it be committed with 100 revision or 200 revision..?

Comment: You can only commit in the HEAD (i.e. 200) revision. There is no way to go back and change an existing commit in the past. If you need rev. 100 to become HEAD, just commit after you revert (this will become rev. 201). Then you can do changes as normal.

Comment: @ Peter You mean if commit any thing new from 100 revision, previous 101 to 200 revisions cannot be changed.. Right..?

Comment: You CANNOT commit to revision. You only commit to head. And you always commit your working copy. So when you update to rev. 100, you effectively make your working copy look like rev 100. Then you commit this, which becomes 201. Again, you can't modify existing commits, only create new ones.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using client follow as shown pic. Once done commit the code again.

[image: access update to revision]